# Getting a user specific path without knowing the username

Tags: c#, url, webbrowser-control

I have a HTML file in `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\myapp\file.html`. I am accessing the file through a web Browser in my C# application to preview it from within the app.
However, when the app is put onto another computer, the address in webBrowser1 is still specific to my username, and therefore other people cannot access the preview.

Is there a way to get to the file as a URL in my web Browser without having the hard coded username in the URL?

What I have tried:

1. C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\myapp\file.html
2. C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\myapp\file.html

Thanks!

Here is the code I used after I was helped:

```
string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string address = Path.Combine(folderPath + @"\myapp\file.html");
webBrowser1.Navigate(address);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get the name of the current logged in user you have to read `Environment.UserName` property.

Moreover if you need to access the `AppData` directory for the roaming user you can get the folder path without hard-coding anything (do not forget that users directory isn't always `c:\users` on every Windows version and path for `AppData` may vary too):

```
string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

In you case simply append the file name:

```
string url = Path.Combine(folderPath, "file.htm");
```

**Notes**
If, for any reason, you need to use environment variables then you have first to expand them:

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\");
```

Comment: @Nathan I suggest you do not build the path, the path is different on XP/Vista and it may be localized. It's better to use GetFolderPath() to get the full-right-safe path so OS you're running on doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code in my post and my app. I am on Windows 7 and it is the only windows version I have done development on, so i had no idea that the file path would be different :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this function. It returns the path of Current User's Application Data Folder.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```